# Difference between jumper wires and jumper leads

Tags: connector, wire, breadboard, jumper

I'd like to know what is the difference between a jumper wire and a jumper lead; sometime I found that they are synonims, other times I found that a jumper wire is the following:

[image]

other times I found that a jumper wire is a male-female wire:

[image]

Comment: I don't think the term "jumper" implies the gender of the wire/connector. It depends on your use case. For breadboarding applications it usually means male-male (or bare single core wire). In other cases where you have exposed male headers it could very well mean female-female or a combination of the two. I also don't think there is a difference between a jumper "wire" and jumper "lead". It's just terminology that people use interchangeably.

Comment: Is there a difference between "wire" and "lead"? "Jumper"'s common to both terms.

Comment: Hello @Andyaka thank you for your comment. I know that a wire can be a lead, but a lead can be a wire or can be a solid conductor with a specific shape.

Comment: Would you care to say with this question might be important to you?

Comment: @Andyaka I'd like to know the difference just for curiosity and to be precise when I write some report to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Nobody's going to worry about that realistically.

Comment: "Leads" may or may not imply specialized connectors or clips on the end. Something other than just a wire.

Answer (score -2):

There are as many "standards" in that regard as there are people using those terms. Such is life.